# Javascript single select option multiple values in HTA

Tags: javascript, html, vbscript, hta

i have a working HTA to wakeup/reboot/shutdown multiple computers with vbscript.
One single select dropdown, with 3 buttons to do 3 different functions.

main hta:

```
        <select name="Control_PC">
            <option value="0" selected>Select Computer</option>     
            <option value="1">PC1</option>
            <option value="2">PC2</option>
            <option value="3">PC3</option>

            <input type="button"    value="WAKE UP"         onClick="executewake">
            <input type="button"    value="RESTART"         onClick="executereboot">
            <input type="button"    value="SHUTDOWN"        onClick="executeshutdown">  
        </select>
```

with the vbscript:

```html
 ' SELECTION REBOOT PCs
 Sub executereboot
  if Control_PC.value = 1 then 
   Set Shell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") : command = "shutdown -r -t 01 -m \\PC1"
   Shell.Run command, 1, false
  Elseif Control_PC.value = 2 then 
   Set Shell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") : command = "shutdown -r -t 01 -m \\PC2"
   Shell.Run command, 1, false
  Elseif Control_PC.value = 3 then 
   Set Shell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") : command = "shutdown -r -t 01 -m \\PC3"
   Shell.Run command, 1, false
  end if 
 End Sub  
 
 
 ' SELECTION SHUTDOWN PCs
 Sub executeshutdown
  if Control_PC.value = 1 then 
   Set Shell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") : command = "shutdown -s -t 01 -m \\PC1"
   Shell.Run command, 1, false
  Elseif Control_PC.value = 2 then 
   Set Shell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") : command = "shutdown -s -t 01 -m \\PC2"
   Shell.Run command, 1, false
  Elseif Control_PC.value = 3 then 
   Set Shell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") : command = "shutdown -s -t 01 -m \\PC3"
   Shell.Run command, 1, false
  end if 
 End Sub   
 
 
 ' SELECTION WAKE PCs
 Sub executewake
  if Control_PC.value = 1 then 
   Set Shell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") : command = "tools\wol.exe 10604B7609CE"
   Shell.Run command, 1, false
  Elseif Control_PC.value = 2 then 
   Set Shell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") : command = "tools\wol.exe 10604B7609F2"
   Shell.Run command, 1, false
  Elseif Control_PC.value = 3 then 
   Set Shell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") : command = "tools\wol.exe 10604B7E829B"
   Shell.Run command, 1, false
  end if 
 End Sub
```

Now i know how to create the select option with one button in javascript, using one value:

```html
   
  <select id="Control_PC">
    <option value="" selected>Select Computer</option>
    <option value="shutdown -r -t 01 -m \\PC1">PC1</option>
    <option value="shutdown -r -t 01 -m \\PC2">PC2</option>
    <option value="shutdown -r -t 01 -m \\PC3">PC3</option>
    <input  type="button" value="Reboot"  onClick="runSelection(document.getElementById('Control_PC').value)">
  </select>
```

But how to create three buttons with javascript to behave the same as the vbscript version, with an elegant solution that would use all the wake/reboot/shutdown commands as different values in one function, something like:

Select Computer
PC1
PC2
PC3

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you can do what you're looking to do by sending variables to the functions you call.

For example, you can set the MAC address as the value of the select box like this:

```
    <select name="Control_PC">
        <option value="" selected>Select Computer</option>      
        <option value="10604B7609CE">PC1</option>
        <option value="10604B7609F2">PC2</option>
        <option value="10604B7E829B">PC3</option>
    </select>
```

Then you can set each button to call the same function with a parameter for what action you want to do, like this:

```
    <input type="button"    value="WAKE UP"         onClick="RunSelection('wake')">
    <input type="button"    value="RESTART"         onClick="RunSelection('restart')">
    <input type="button"    value="SHUTDOWN"        onClick="RunSelection('shutdown')">
```

Then you can configure that vbscript function to perform specific actions based on the value of that parameter and the value of the select box. Like this:

```
Sub RunSelection(strAction)
    If Control_PC.selectedIndex = 0 Then MsgBox "Select a computer.",vbExclamation : Exit Sub 
    pcName = Control_PC.Options(Control_PC.selectedIndex).innerText
    macAddress = Control_PC.value

    Select Case strAction
        Case "wake"
            strCommand = "tools\wol.exe " & macAddress
        Case "restart"
            strCommand = "shutdown -r -t 01 -m \\" & pcName
        Case "shutdown"
            strCommand = "shutdown -s -t 01 -m \\" & pcName
    End Select 
    MsgBox "Running command: " & strCommand
End Sub
```

There are many ways to do what you're trying to do, but this should help you get started.

Edit to OP's comment:

I think what you're looking to do is something like this.

```
<select name="Control_PC">
    <option value="" selected>Select Computer</option>      
    <option restart="shutdown -r -t 01 -m \\PC1"  shutdown="shutdown -s -t 01 -m \\PC1" >PC1</option>
    <option restart="shutdown -r -t 01 -m \\PC2"  shutdown="shutdown -s -t 01 -m \\PC2" >PC2</option>
    <option restart="shutdown -r -t 01 -m \\PC3"  shutdown="shutdown -s -t 01 -m \\PC3" >PC3</option>

</select>
<input  type="button" value="Restart"    onClick="RunSelection(Control_PC.Options(Control_PC.selectedIndex).getAttribute('restart'))">
<input  type="button" value="Shutdown"    onClick="RunSelection(Control_PC.Options(Control_PC.selectedIndex).getAttribute('shutdown'))">
```

Essentially you're creating a custom attribute and assigning it a value.

`Control_PC.Options(Control_PC.selectedIndex)` will get the selected option and `getAttribute` will get the value of the attribute you specify.

Comment: Thanks, but i was thinking about javascript. to have the onclick function document.getElementById   with different values

Comment: Then I think your question is more about the HTML syntax. I'll edit my answer.